# Intercept dynamic function calls (like laravel HasAttribute trait)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7.1

Consider the follow class `A`:

```
public class A
{
  //...
}
```

and the following snippet:

```
$a = new A();
$value = $a->getFooValue();
```

As you can see `getFooValue` is not defined on `A`, I would like to intercept the function *key* (in this cas `foo`) and then handle it with some custom logic.

I am trying to do something similar to [laravel mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators) where I can have for example a method called `getFooAttribute` and Laravel will handle it with the **[HasAttribute](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php)** trait.

For example if I call `getFooAttribute` laravel will handle it, and understand that the `foo` and then will perform some check to find if there's the attribute or the mutator.

Any reference or idea would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can intercept calls to undefined methods of an object by implementing the magic **__call()** method - see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call for more details.

Example from the docs:

```
public function __call($name, $arguments)
{
    echo "Calling object method '$name' " . implode(', ', $arguments). "\n";
}
```

Comment: Correct, actually I have just seen it as well and was going to answer my own question! Thanks :)